# Please help me solve this tautological proof

Tags: logic, proof-writing

I'm studying for an upcoming exam and have run across this tautological proof:

$(R\to Q)\to ((J\land\neg K)\to [(J\equiv Q)\lor(K\equiv R)])$

To start this one off, I decided to create two conditional proofs.

1. $(R\to Q)$

   2. $(J\land\neg K)$

*The second assumed antecedent is nested within the first if that wasn't clear.*

So now I am trying to prove $(J\equiv Q)\lor(K\equiv R)]$ using the conditional proof method. I can easily isolate J and ~K, but I am a little lost as to where to proceed from here. I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the outline. Details will depend on your definition of the equivalence operator.
$\def\imp{\rightarrow}$

If $R \imp Q$:

If $J \land \neg K$:

$J$.

$\neg K$.

$R \lor \neg R$.

If $R$:

$Q$.

$J \equiv Q$.

If $\neg R$:

$R \equiv K$.

$( J \equiv Q ) \lor ( R \equiv K )$.

$J \land \neg K \imp ( ( J \equiv Q ) \lor ( R \equiv K ) )$.

$(R \imp Q ) \imp ( J \land \neg K \imp ( ( J \equiv Q ) \lor ( R \equiv K ) ) )$.

Comment: Thank you for posting this outline! I have a few questions though. How were you able to get R v ~R? I can see how to get ~R v Q from material implication of line 1, but I don't see how we can get R or ~R by itself.

Comment: @Jerry: It is an axiom in classical logic. You cannot derive it from the other rules.

Comment: @Jerry: Do you get it? If you used truth tables to define the logical operators and/or/not/implies/equiv then the justification of the axiom $R \lor \neg R$ is simply that it is always true regardless of the truth value of $R$. So we are allowed to use it anywhere we like.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a proof based on the hint suggested by user21820:

[image]

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/